# WordPress add rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Im trying to add a custom url strcuture as followed

Original url:
http://www.somedomain.com/?p=305&calyear=2019&calmonth=04

Permalink:
http://www.somedomain.com/somepage/?calyear=2019&calmonth=04

Wanted url:
http://www.somedomain.com/calendar/2019/04/

I have added the following rule:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^calendar\/(.+)\/(.+)\/?$','index.php?page_id=305&calyear=$matches[1]&calmonth=$matches[2]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Although im getting the correct page,

```
$wp_query->query_vars['calyear']
$wp_query->query_vars['calmonth']
```

Does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rewrite code is fine you just need to add one filter which is **query_vars**.
So complete code is like this.

```
 function custom_rewrite_rule() 
 {
      add_rewrite_rule('^calendar\/(.+)\/(.+)\/?$','index.php?page_id=305&calyear=$matches[1]&calmonth=$matches[2]','top');
 }

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

**Add query_vars filter**

```
function set_query_varaible( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'calyear';
    $query_vars[] = 'calmonth';     

   return $query_vars;
}

   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'set_query_varaible' );
```

Comment: You are a Genius :)

Comment: Thank you Lior  :)